# Updating Identity with DELETE - OUTPUT - INSERT

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert, uniqueidentifier, sql-delete, database-deadlocks

I need to update an identity column in a very specific scenario (most of the time the identity will be left alone). When I do need to update it, I simply need to give it a new value and so I'm trying to use a `DELETE + INSERT` combo.
At present I have a working query that looks something like this:

```
DELETE Test_Id
OUTPUT DELETED.Data, 
       DELETED.Moredata 
INTO Test_id 
WHERE  Id = 13
```

(This is only an example, the real query is slightly more complex.)
A colleague brought up an important point. She asked if this wont cause a deadlock since we are writing and reading from the same table. Although in the example it works fine (half a dozen rows), in a real world scenario with tens of thousands of rows this might not work.

Is this a real issue? If so, is there a way to prevent it?

I set up an <kbd>[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d083/1)</kbd>.
Thanks!

Comment: Interesting idea. If this is an index key then chances are the corresponding update, even if it was allowed (e.g. for columns with a sequence rather than identity), would just be implemented as a delete + insert anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought was, yes it can. And maybe it is still possible, however in this simplified version of the statement it would be very hard to hit an deadlock. You're selecting a single row for which probably row level locks are acquired plus the fact that the locks required for the delete and the insert are acquired very fast after each other.

I've did some testing against a table holding a million rows execution the statement 5 million times on 6 different connections in parallel. Did not hit a single deadlock.

But add the reallive query, an table with indexes and foreign keys and you just might have a winner. I've had a similar statement which did cause deadlocks.

I have encountered deadlock errors with a similar statement.

```
UPDATE A
SET x=0
OUTPUT INSERTED.ID, 'a' INTO B
```

So for this statement to complete mssql needs to take locks for the updates on table A, locks for the inserts on table B and shared (read) locks on table A to validate the foreign key table B has to table A.

And last but not least, mssql decided it would be wise to use parallelism on this particular query causing the statement to deadlock on itself. To resolve this I've simply set "MAXDOP 1" query hint on the statement to prevent parallelism.

There is however no definite answer to prevent deadlocks. As they say with mssql ever so ofter, it depends. You could take an exclusive using the TABLOCKX table hint. This will prevent a deadlock, however it's probably not desirable for other reasons.